# How to underline text using printf in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console

I note the question [Colorful text using printf in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765938/colorful-text-using-printf-in-c/) gives a good example of setting coloured text on the standard console output in Windows. Is there something similar that allows output to be underlined? Or possibly even bolded or italicised?

EDIT: I tried Lundin's answer on using COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE with no luck. Attempting to use AddFontResource() to add arial italic font to try italics gives an error that there is an `undefined reference to __imp_AddFontResourceA`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do so using any standard C functions, as the C language doesn't even recognize the presence of a screen.

With Windows API [console functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682087%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can change colors, underline and some other things. The particular function you are looking for is called [SetConsoleTextAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) just as in the post you linked. Change its [attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_character_attributes) to include `COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE`.

Comment: No luck with that on my win7 system, with that option turned on, all the printf() string chars are printed as spaces, except new-lines :(

Comment: @Toby Hmm, so it seems. Been ages since I used these functions. I'll do some research, see if I can find out why.

Comment: The `COMMON_LVB_*` attributes are only used for [`CHAR_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attributes when the console is using a [DBCS codepage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317794%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You might run your program in some environment with a terminal accepting [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

<sup>(I never used Windows - since I am using Linux only -, so I don't know how to set up such environment in Windows; but I heard that it is possible)</sup>

With ANSI escape codes, underlining is `"\e[4m"` with `\e` being the ASCII ESCAPE character.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try using termcaps. Something like this (after initializing termcaps) :

```
printf(tgetstr("us", NULL)); /* underline on */
printf(""/* your string */);
printf(tgetstr("ue", NULL)); /* underline off */
```

or more concise :

```
printf("%s/* your text here */%s", tgetstr("us", NULL), tgetstr("ue", NULL));
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_node/termcap_34.html

Answer (score -2):

The '\r' sequence differs from the newline ('\n') in that it moves the cursor to the
beginning of the current line of output, not to the beginning of the next line. Using
'\r' gives a program the ability to create a file containing more than one character
in one line position.

This prints an underlined text
printf("\f\t\t\tFinal Report\r\t\t\t____________\n");

Comment: No. It would overwrite the text, and would only show the underline