# How to print a certain text in colour in C

Tags: c, windows, console

Is there anyway to make a printf and have only a certain part of the text displayed in the console in colour?

For example, let's say I'm about to print:

```
printf("a b c");
```

Is there anyway to print only one of those letters in colour?
Can I have an output in the Windows console that only displays one of them in colour?
If so, how should I do it and what library should I use?

Comment: see this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219393/stdlib-and-colored-output-in-c

Comment: @kapil, op wants it in windows console.The link which you gave is for Unix systems.

Comment: I actually tried with that answer, but it wont work

Comment: that's right, that one is for Unix systems

Comment: @JoelFloresSottile check this. I am not sure whether it will work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765938/colorful-text-using-printf-in-c

Comment: If the above one doesn't work, check this.  http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/17822-print-certain-text-in-color/

Comment: I'll try it out, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [windows console API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for example the function **[`SetConsoleTextAttribute()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**:

```
#include <windows.h>
...
   SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                        BACKGROUND_INTENSITY|FOREGROUND_BLUE);
```

You would have to make such kind of calls to set attributes every time you want to change them before doing the `printf()`.  But be careful:  this function is specific to windows and not portable.