# printf html span not working

Tags: html, c++, c, printf

I am trying to change the font and color of the text in a printf statement. I cant get the below statement to work. Is there a library needed to use html with printf?

```
printf("<span font_desc='Sans 24' color='white'>Hello</span>"
       "<span font_desc='Sans 24' color='green'>World</span>\n");
```

I even tried something simple to bold the font and cant get it to work.

```
printf("<b>Hello</b>");
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Aren't tags closed with forward-slashed instead of backslashes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765938/colorful-text-using-printf-in-c`

Comment: Fixed the typos in my question. Thank you for the link but they focus on the changing the color of the text. I also need to change the font type.

Comment: Did you view source to make sure the results make sense, and match a working page created with a text editor?  Or to back up, are you writing a .HTML page  to be viewed in a browser?  This is unlikely to work in other contexts.

Comment: In which context does your program run? Is it supposed to create HTML pages, for example by running it as CGI-BIN? Or is it supposed to run in a shell? If the latter is the case, you have to use the shell-specific commands, not the HTML-"commands".