# How to change the text color in C programming in Dev C++?

Tags: c

My code is showing as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void red () {
  printf("\033[1;31m");
}
void yellow (){
  printf("\033[1;33m");
}
void reset () {
  printf("\033[0m");
}
int main () {
  red();
  printf("Hello ");
  yellow();
  printf("world\n");
  reset();
  return 0;
}
```

When I run using Dev C++ as IDE, the output display somehow is not showing the right color/ Instead, it was showing as a bunch of regular text. How can I fix this in Dev C++?

[image]

Comment: I recommend you to use Windows API function `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` to set console text color in Windows.

Comment: The terminal you are using clearly does not support the escape codes you are trying to use.

Comment: for the old conhost terminal you may need to enable ANSI sequence support manually [Windows console with ANSI colors handling](https://superuser.com/a/1300251/241386), [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35864976/995714)

Answer (score -2):

What you need is called ANSI escape sequences for certain colors

Have a look here, I think this is what are you looking for
[colorful text using printf in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765938/colorful-text-using-printf-in-c)

Comment: The escape sequences can be seen on the screenshot.